# Error : “Thread-1” java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I have some code for a trivia/unscramble bot which ran inside a server in which the user tries to guess the answer to a question before the time is up. The code compiles fine however after running the thread for about 30-45 minutes, I get an error and the trivia stops working. Here is the error I get:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 
  Index: 973, Size 965
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.emulinker.kaillera.model.impl.Trivia.run(Trivia.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is the code for `org.emulinker.kaillera.model.impl.Trivia`, starting at line 249:

```
        else{
            temp = generator.nextInt(questions.size() - 1);
            questions_count = questions_num.get(temp);
            questions_num.remove(temp);
        }
```

Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Format the code and specify the line number.

Comment: which line is throwing exception?

Comment: `temp = generator.nextInt(questions.size() - 1);` throws the exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what other information Java could *give* you to make this any easier.

It tells you the *exact* line `Trivia.java:251`, the collection size `965` and the index you're trying to use `973`. Surely that's enough to be getting on with?

Normally there'd be little chance of me trying to figure out which of those several hundred lines is line 251, however, I'm bored at the moment so I'll give it a shot (and, in any case, you've since replaced the massive code dump with just the relevant lines). The errant line appears to be:

```
 else{
     temp = generator.nextInt(questions.size() - 1);
     questions_count = questions_num.get(temp);       // << THIS ONE
     questions_num.remove(temp);
 }
```

Now I'm not going to go through the entirety of your "War and Peace"-style code snippet that you seem to think satisfies the "smallest example that exhibits the problem" :-)

But I'd say it's a safe bet that `questions` and `questions_num` have diverged in size somewhere, assuming they even *were* the same size at some point in the past. Quite possibly they've diverged due to that third line in the `else` block above or, more precisely, the lack of a fourth line that affects `questions` in the same way.

The fact that you got 973 from the generator using `questions`, despite the size of `questions_num` being only 965, makes this a near certainty.

Perhaps it might be a good idea to keep them in sync.

Comment: Thanks for the help, sorry about the code snippet. So to fix this problem I need to synchronize questions and questions_num? I'm fairly new to programming and I am only attempting to "fix" what I believe are minor bugs in a program that I use daily so that the community I'm in can enjoy a working server. In other words, can you break it down for me and explain it to me like I was a kindergartner? :)

Comment: @user3085046, don't be usin' those high-falutin' German words here, when 'beginner' would do just as well :-) But, humour aside, yes. Assuming they are _meant_ to be in sync, it's a bad idea to remove index `temp` from `questions_num` and _not_ `questions` as well. If they're _not_ meant to be in sync, you probably want to use `temp = generator.nextInt(questions_num.size() - 1);` instead. It all comes down to intent which, unfortunately, I don't know because I don't really want to read 450-odd lines of code :-)

Comment: That didn't work but thanks alot for helping I'll try and figure it out

Comment: @user3085046, well, at least you know the specific problem, the fact that you're using a different sized collection for generating an index into a _smaller_ collection. From there, it should be at least a _little_ easier to track down the root cause. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

> Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   Index: 973, Size 965

This exception is self explanatory . Size of `questions_num` is 965 and your are trying to access it outside the bounds `i.e. 973`

As [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) says

> `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is Thrown to indicate that an index of some sort (such as to an array, to
>   a string, or to a vector) is out of range.